# Sum of correlated random variables and the Law of Large Numbers?

Tags: probability, problem-solving, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ which can take values on the set $\mathcal{X}=\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ and $X$ is drawn according to the given probability mass function  $\mathbf{p}=\{p_1,p_2,\dots,p_m\}$. Let $S(X)$ be a 'well-behaved' function. Then I want to calculate the following sum:

\begin{equation}
\bar{S_n}:=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \prod_{i=1}^k S(X_i)
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

where the $X_i$'s are drawn i.i.d $\sim \mathbf{p}$. Explicitly, the average is:

\begin{equation}
\bar{S_n}:=\frac{1}{n} \{S(X_1)+S(X_1)S(X_2)+\cdots+S(X_1)\cdots S(X_n)\}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

This can be seen as a sum of correlated random variables.

**Question.** Is there a version of the Law of Large Numbers which can be applied here in order to write the limit of $\bar{S_n}$ in terms of the p.m.f. $\mathbf{p}$?

Comment: I assume the $X_i$ are iid samples of $X$. If $S$ takes large enough values this sum is dominated by its largest term, which is the last term. This last term can be analyzed by applying the central limit theorem to its logarithm. You get log normal fluctuations around a typical value.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But what if the $n-1$ term is of the same order as the $n$-th term? Or what about if $S(X_i)<1$ for all the $X_i$'s?

Comment: Then you should specify that in the problem; if $S(X_i) < c < 1$ for a fixed constant $c$ then the sum is now dominated by its first term, and otherwise things seem complicated.

Comment: I think, this will be of little help, but maybe you will find something useful for yourself: [There is yet no general method to find the distribution in renewal risk model](https://www.soa.org/library/proceedings/arch/2009/arch-2009-iss1-dufresne-dis.pdf), however some distributions are known. Of course there are many generalizations of LLN, [for example](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3844.pdf) in terms of $(S_n - ES_n)/n \rightarrow 0$ for non-negative random variables in sums (you can take logarithms of addends).

Comment: Let $m=E(\log |S(X_1)|)$. If $m<0$, then $\bar S_n\to0$ almost surely. If $m>0$, then $(\bar S_n)$ diverges almost surely. Are you assuming that $m=0$?

Comment: @Did How did you arrived to your conclusion? And answering your question, the case $m=0$ is not interesting. I ask for your train of thought because maybe it will help me to obtain an expression for $\bar{S_n}$ for large values of $n$.

Comment: Law of large numbers + the obvious $\left|\prod S(X_k)\right|=\exp\left(\sum\log|S(X_k)|\right)$ + Cesaro.